# math functions on datatable values, using array maybe?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

could i take values (all bigints) from a datatable and apply math functions to them? For example, lets say (all record 1):

```
Column 1 = 10;
Column 2 = 20;
Column 3 = 5;
Column 4 = 60;
```

Now, can i make a math equation from those eg. (column1 + colum2)-(column3 * column4)

Is this possible, maybe using a array???

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this trick to get the result of all the rows:

```
//Suppose you create your DataTable like this:
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col1",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Col2",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Col3",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Col4",typeof(int));
//Add some rows to test
dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3, 4);
dt.Rows.Add(2, 2, 2, 2);
dt.Rows.Add(4, 2, 3, 3);

//Use this method to extract the result, remember that it's just demo
private List<int> GetResultColumn(DataTable dt){
  dt.Columns.Add("Result",typeof(int));
  dt.Columns["Result"].Expression = "(Col1+Col2)-(Col3*Col4)";
  List<int> result = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int>("Result")).ToList();
  dt.Columns.Remove("Result");
  return result;
}
//Use it
var result = GetResultColumn(dt);
//output  {0, -9, 0, -3}
```

You can always loop through the rows and do it in **a more standard way** like this:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(row=> row.Field<int>("Col1")+row.Field<int>("Col2") 
                            -row.Field<int>("Col3")*row.Field<int>("Col4"))
               .ToList();//Remove ToList() if you want
```

### UPDATE:

```
var newestRow = dt.AsEnumerable().Max(row=>row.Field<int>("ID"));
var result = newestRow.Field<int>("Col1") + newestRow.Field<int>("Col2") 
             -newestRow.Field<int>("Col3")* newestRow.Field<int>("Col4");
```

Comment: i only need one row, which would be determined by the ID?

Comment: so for example the values of all the colums in row 1 would be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 hypothetically, i need to perform complex math on those numbers?

Comment: @tonyb your `DataTable` would have many rows, but you want to calculate for only 1 row, so how do you determine what row? by its row index?

Comment: @tonyb don't understand, the only way you can determine the row is by its `RowIndex`, or by some `Filter expression` against the `DataTable`, Now I'm really confused about what actually you want.

Comment: I will select the newest row (which i will find by its ID column), then the rest of the columns are integers. I need to use these values in a math equation

Comment: how would i use integers put into text boxes in a math equation, thats probably easier? i.e. textbox1 = 1, textbox2 = 2 etc, then textbox1+textbox2. Ive tried but it uses these as strings?

Comment: @tonyb just convert the `result` into `string` and assign that converted string to your `textBox.Text` like this `textBox.Text = result.ToString()`;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39124/discussion-between-tony-b-and-king-king)

Comment: sorry, i didnt write it clearly, instead of using the values from a datatable, how would i use the values in the textboxes on my form (the table gets its info from these) in a math formula?

Comment: @tonyb do you mean all the `operands` are stored in your `textboxes`?

Comment: yes, i think ive got it, i just converted them all to int32 and assigned a variable int as my equation?? like int a = convert.toint32(textbox1).....int answer = (a+b)*c

Comment: @tonyb yes, looks like your problem is `how to convert string to int`

Comment: ah, new problem now though, will post a new question if you wouldnt mind taking a look?

Comment: @tonyb of course, go ahead, you should try to describe your problem exactly, directly, with possible examples, people here will always try to help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

if i want to make: Result = (1 / Priority) * JobComplex

example: if enginners have Jobs with:

Enginner Jhon: Priority = 2, JobComplex = 2; then (1/2) * 2 = 1

Enginner Mark: Priority = 1, JobComplex = 3; then (1/1) * 3 = 3

then Enginner Mark is more Busy.

```
List<DataRow> theRows = new List<DataRow>();
decimal relativeBusy = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in EnginnerTable.Rows)
{    
 //1.- Get list of rows that match an "ID_Enginner"
 theRows = JobsTable.Select("ID_EnginnerAsigned=" + row["ID_Enginner"]).ToList();
 relativeBusy = 0;

 //2.- Foreach in "theRows" list, and make the math: Result = (1 / Priority) * JobComplex
 //** Priority and JobComplex are Columns...
 foreach (DataRow row2 in theRows)
 { 
   relativeBusy = relativeBusy + ((1 / Convert.ToDecimal(row2["Priority"])) * Convert.ToDecimal(row2["JobComplex"]));
 }

 //3.- Save the result on a List<decimal> to add to "Relative" Column of a Table after...
 jobsrelativeBusy.Add(relativeBusy);
}
```

you can make the math more complex...